# Tag Search is Case Sensitive in Android App

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

In the Android app, when I search using `Tags` (by actually clicking on the site name and switching from `Questions` to `Tags`) the search is case sensitive. For example, on my phone when I type "Android" it capitalizes the "A" and doesn't return any results. Only after a change the "A" to lower case does it find results such as [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app).

In my opinion, I think it would be more user friendly for the search to be case insensitive. Similar to the new way of adding tags to the question on the app. So for example, when creating this question, I typed "Android" and [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) showed up in the results.

I'm on version 0.1.70

**Update**

The fix that went out in version 0.1.71 fixed the issue when a bracket `[` is included but it is still case sensitive when one is not. I know there are some cases where including brackets in a search provides much better results, but I wasn't including it in my search only because `Tags` is already selected. Please see the two screenshots below:

- Search with no bracket returns no results

[image: No results displayed when no bracket is included]

---

- Search beginning with a bracket does return results

[image: Results are displayed when a bracket is included]

Still tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) since I'm not able to remove it. Please let me know if any additional details are needed.

Comment: I would argue this is a [bug] and not a [feature-request]

Comment: @StevenV I was going back and forth on the two and ended up choosing feature-request, and to be honest I'm not quite sure why, but I do agree with you. It's changed now, and thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please notify Kasra that it's still not working, he's not getting notification for edits you make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in version 0.1.71 coming out later tonight (in UTC), thanks!

Comment: nIce fiX! ^___^

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi thanks, I'll test after the update and mark as answer.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi please see my update

Comment: @Brian My bad, better fix coming out tonight.